# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: data Filename: profile/viewabout.php Line Number: 79

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop, undefined, codeigniter-3

**Controller:**   I'm trying to fetch the records from database, but it is showing undefined variable $data in the view section. What is the problem i don't understand.

```
public function vabout(){
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        redirect('register/login');
    }
    $this->load->model('profile_model');
    $data = $this->profile_model->viewprofile();

    $this->load->view('templates/pheader');
    $this->load->view('profile/viewabout',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/pfooter');

}
```

**Model:** This is the model section, is there any issue in model for fetching the record?

```
public function viewprofile(){
    $data = $this->db->get('profile');
    return $data->row_array();
}
```

**View:** errore: a php error encountered 
$data is  undefined

```
<?php
      foreach ($data as $row)
        { ?>
        <p><?php echo $row->id; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $row->name; ?></p>
        <?php
      }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass array with `key` name `$data`not contain `data` as key name, Every `key` you pass with `data` array will become variable in view

```
public function vabout(){
                if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
                    redirect('register/login');
                }
                $this->load->model('profile_model');
                $data['data'] = $this->profile_model->viewprofile(); // add data as index

                $this->load->view('templates/pheader');
                $this->load->view('profile/viewabout',$data);
                $this->load->view('templates/pfooter');

            }
```

Also you are retrieving data in view like object. So in model not convert result in array

```
public function viewprofile(){
    $data = $this->db->get('profile');
    return $data->result();
}
```

Comment: it didn't work @B. Desai Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this: Controller

```
 public function vabout($id = NULL){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('register/login');
        }
        $this->load->model('profile_model');
        $data['data'] = $this->profile_model->viewprofile($id);

        $this->load->view('templates/pheader');
        $this->load->view('profile/viewabout',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/pfooter');

    }
```

Replacing model with this. Is it right then?

Model:

```
public function viewprofile($id = FALSE){
     if($id === FALSE){
        $query = $this->db->get('profile');
        return $query->result_array();
      }
         $query = $this->db->get_where('profile',array('id' => $id);
         return $query->row_array();
    }
```

View:

```
<?php
              foreach ($data as $row)
                { ?>
                <p><?php echo $row['id']; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
                <?php
              }
          ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @flixy it worked....

Comment: Anytime @SohailShaikh

Comment: @SohailShaikh  two returns in same function, are you serious it worked?

Comment: Ya @AlivetoDie I am also surprised. Also in model `$id` must be undeined error. I have suggested same solution (but with object).And here he says it worked, ;p

Comment: Yes @AlivetoDie

Comment: And also flixy know that `$id` will be there in controller `vabout($id = NULL)`  @AlivetoDie. :D

Comment: yes i'm also a bit confused though @B.Desai but it is working...

Comment: Ya this edited one is also working @flixy